# Datatables no refresca/actualiza la tabla después de realizar algun cambio

Tags: html, html5, ajax, datatables, alertify

He creada una tabla con código *HMTL* junto con **Bootstrap 4** de la siguiente manera:

```
<table class="table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="tabla-publicaciones" name="tabla-publicaciones">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Fecha recibido</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th><button class="btn btn-primary btn-icono" id="btn-publicaciones-nueva" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-publicaciones"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></button></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
```

Y para agregar diversas funcionalidades/herramientas para manipular los datos que se muestran en la tabla uso **Datatables** a través del siguiente código JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
listarNoticias();
$("#btn-guardar-noticia").click(function() {
enviarNoticia();
});
});

function listarNoticias() {//Esta función re/inicializa el DataTables
var accion = "tabla-noticia";
var tabla = $("#tabla-noticias").DataTable({
"destroy":true,
"ajax":{
  "method":"POST",
  "url":"<?php echo SERVIDOR ?>/App/Servidor/CtrlDAONoticias.php",
  "data":{"accion":accion}
},
"columns":[
  {"data":"Fecha"},
  {"data":"Titulo"},
  {"data":"cantidad_comentarios"},
  {"defaultContent":"<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-icono' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-noticia' id='btn-editar-noticia'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></button>", "orderable": false}
],
"language": {
  "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json"
}
});
obtenerDatosNoticia("#tabla-noticias tbody", tabla);
}

var obtenerDatosNoticia = function(tbody, tabla) {//Esta función llena los campos del formulario obteniendo la información de la fila
$(tbody).on("click", "#btn-editar-noticia", function() {
var datos = tabla.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
var id_noticia = $("#id-noticia").val(datos.Id);
var titulo = $("#titulo-noticia").val(datos.Titulo);
if (datos.Estado == 'Publicada') {
  $("#estado-noticia").prop("checked", true);
} else {
  $("#estado-noticia").prop("checked", false);
}
var texto = $("#cuerpo-noticia").val(datos.Texto);
if (datos.Imagen !== null) {
  $("#img-imagen-noticia").attr("src", "../Archivos/Subidas/Noticias/"+datos.Imagen);
  $("#img-imagen-noticia").prop("hidden", false);
}
});
}

function enviarNoticia() {//Esta función va hacia la base de datos para insertar/actualizar un registro y dependiendo de la respuesta se muestra una notificación diferente
var id_noticia = $("#id-noticia").val();
var id_persona_noticia = $("#id-persona-noticia").val();
var titulo_noticia = $("#titulo-noticia").val();
if ($('#estado-noticia').is(":checked")) {
var estado_noticia ='Publicada';
} else {
var estado_noticia ='Sin publicar';
}
var cuerpo_noticia = $("#cuerpo-noticia").val();
var accion = "insertar-actualizar-noticia";
var cadena = "Id-noticia="+id_noticia+"&Id-persona-noticia="+id_persona_noticia+"&Titulo-noticia="+titulo_noticia+"&Estado-noticia="+estado_noticia+"&Cuerpo-noticia="+cuerpo_noticia+"&accion="+accion;
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:"<?php echo SERVIDOR ?>/App/Servidor/CtrlDAONoticias.php",
data:cadena,
success:function(r){
  if(r==1) {
    listarNoticias();//Aquí debería inicializar la tabla despues de que los cambios se guarden, pero sale un error
    alertify.success("Noticia enviada exitosamente");
  } else {
    alertify.error("Hay un error");
  }
}
});
}
```

Adicionalmente utilizo **Alertify** para mostrar notificaciones al usuario de acuerdo a la acción que acaba de realizar.

Todo el código JavaScript se encarga de inicializar el DataTables, mostrar un modal con un formulario, también tiene funciones para crear, modificar y/o eliminar un elemento de la tabla.

La tabla funciona correctamente, el problema es que para poder ver los cambios debo actualizar toda la página del navegador web, porque no se actualiza automáticamente el DataTables (**SintaxError data Undefined**). Cabe señalar que después de recibir una respuesta del Ajax llamo la *función listarNoticias();* que se encarga de inicializar el DataTables con toda la información traída de la base de datos MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se genera debido a la versión de DataTables que uno utiliza, corrigiendo el error el código queda de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
listarNoticias();
$("#btn-guardar-noticia").click(function() {
enviarNoticia();
});
});

function listarNoticias() {
var accion = "tabla-noticia";
var tabla = $("#tabla-noticias").DataTable({
"destroy":true,
"ajax":{
  "method":"POST",
  "url":"<?php echo SERVIDOR ?>/App/Servidor/CtrlDAONoticias.php",
  "data":{"accion":accion}
},
"columns":[
  {"data":"Fecha"},
  {"data":"Titulo"},
  {"data":"cantidad_comentarios"},
  {"defaultContent":"<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-icono' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-noticia' id='btn-editar-noticia'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></button>", "orderable": false}
],
"language": {
  "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json"
}
});
obtenerDatosNoticia("#tabla-noticias tbody", tabla);
}

var obtenerDatosNoticia = function(tbody, tabla) {
$(tbody).on("click", "#btn-editar-noticia", function() {
var datos = tabla.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
var id_noticia = $("#id-noticia").val(datos.Id);
var titulo = $("#titulo-noticia").val(datos.Titulo);
if (datos.Estado == 'Publicada') {
  $("#estado-noticia").prop("checked", true);
} else {
  $("#estado-noticia").prop("checked", false);
}
var texto = $("#cuerpo-noticia").val(datos.Texto);
if (datos.Imagen !== null) {
  $("#img-imagen-noticia").attr("src", "../Archivos/Subidas/Noticias/"+datos.Imagen);
  $("#img-imagen-noticia").prop("hidden", false);
}
});
}

function enviarNoticia() {
var id_noticia = $("#id-noticia").val();
var id_persona_noticia = $("#id-persona-noticia").val();
var titulo_noticia = $("#titulo-noticia").val();
if ($('#estado-noticia').is(":checked")) {
var estado_noticia ='Publicada';
} else {
var estado_noticia ='Sin publicar';
}
var cuerpo_noticia = $("#cuerpo-noticia").val();
var accion = "insertar-actualizar-noticia";
var cadena = "Id-noticia="+id_noticia+"&Id-persona-noticia="+id_persona_noticia+"&Titulo-noticia="+titulo_noticia+"&Estado-noticia="+estado_noticia+"&Cuerpo-noticia="+cuerpo_noticia+"&accion="+accion;
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:"<?php echo SERVIDOR ?>/App/Servidor/CtrlDAONoticias.php",
data:cadena,
success:function(r){
  if(r==1) {
    $('#tabla-publicaciones').DataTable().ajax.reload();//listarNoticias();
    alertify.success("Noticia enviada exitosamente");
  } else {
    alertify.error("Hay un error");
  }
}
});
}
```

Lo que se hizo fue llamar la función *$('#tabla-publicaciones').DataTable().ajax.reload();* en lugar de llamar *listaNoticias();* debido a un cambio del funcionamiento del propio DataTables

Las versiones **1.10.17** y posteriores (actualmente hasta la versión 1.10.19) requiren el realizar este cambio, para que la tabla se actualice sin necesidad de recargar toda la página del navegador web.